# Lower bounding a partition-related sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, partitions

We say the $\mathbb{N}$-valued, non-increasing, eventually zero sequence $\lambda=(\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\cdots)$ is a partition of $N$ if $|\lambda|:=\sum_{k\geq 1}\lambda_k=N$, and denote $m_k(\lambda):=\#\{k\text{ in }\lambda\}$. So for a partition of $N$, $N=|\lambda|=\sum_{k=1}^N km_k(\lambda)$. Since a partition of $N$ can also be viewed as an outcome of a permutation cycle structure of $N$ points, we have $$\sum_{|\lambda|=N}\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^{m_k(\lambda)}m_k(\lambda)!}=1$$ from the random permutation theory.

I want to bound the following sum from below by an absolute constant (so independent of $N$), but I didn't find a simple way as it is from above. The sum is: $$\sum_{|\lambda|=N}\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{2^{m_k(\lambda)}}{k^{m_k(\lambda)}m_k(\lambda)!(m_k(\lambda)+1)!}.$$ Easy to see it is upper bounded by the above formula and thus at most constant order, but how do we show a matching order lower bound to argue that it is indeed of constant order?

Comment: @SamHopkins It arises as a special case in a probability study, and the whole issue is treated in a totally different manner (involving advanced probability ideas like GMC methods). I am wondering whether something can be said using elementary methods in this very special case.

Comment: I wrote some simple Sage code to test this. For instance for $N=50$, your sum evaluates to $0.8039724931...$. Seems plausible that it is converges as $N\to \infty$ to some positive constant.

Comment: I don't know why the answer by @Lucia has been deleted but it can be used to show that the generating function $\sum_{N=0}^\infty\text{(your sum)}(N)z^N$ is$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{I_1\left(2\sqrt\frac{2z^k}k\right)}{\sqrt\frac{2z^k}k}$$where $I_1$ is the first modified Bessel function

Comment: (or if you prefer$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(I_0\left(2\sqrt\frac{2z^k}k\right)-I_2\left(2\sqrt\frac{2z^k}k\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum you want is the coefficient of $z^N$ in the generating function
$$ 
F(z) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \Big( \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^m}{(m+1)!} \frac{z^{km}}{k^m m!}\Big). 
$$
The function $F(z)$ converges absolutely in $|z|<1$, and we can understand it better by writing
$$ 
g(z) = e^{-z} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^m}{(m+1)!} \frac{z^m}{m!},
$$
so that
$$ 
F(z) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{z^k/k} g(z^k/k)= \frac{1}{1-z} G(z), 
$$
say, where
$$ 
G(z) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} g(z^k/k), 
$$
and we used that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^{k}/k = -\log (1-z)$.

Observe that $g(z)$ is a power series $1+ 0\times z+ a_2 z^2 +\ldots$ where the coefficients $a_j$ for $j\ge 2$ may easily be bounded in size by the corresponding coefficient of $e^z \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} z^m/m! = e^{2z}$.  Thus $|a_j| \le 2^j/j!$ for all $j\ge 2$.  Thus if we write
$$ 
G(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b(n) z^n, 
$$
then the coefficients $b(n)$ are bounded in absolute value by the corresponding coefficients of
$$
H(z) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} h(z^k/k), 
$$
with $h(z) = 1+ \sum_{j=2}^{\infty} 2^jz^j/j!$.  Since $h(z)=1+O(|z|^2)$ for $|z|\le 1$, the product defining $H$ converges at $z=1$.  Therefore the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b(n)$ converges absolutely, and thus to its limiting value $G(1)$.

The coefficient of $z^N$ in $F(z)$ equals $b(0)+b(1)+\ldots +b(N)$, which therefore tends to $G(1)$ which equals
$$ 
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-1/k} \Big(1 +\frac 1k + \frac{1}{3k^2} + \frac{1}{18k^3} +\ldots \Big). 
$$

There is an amusing related problem, which I didn't know offhand before.  It is well known that the proportion of square-free integers up to $N$ is $1/\zeta(2) = 6/\pi^2$.   What is the proportion of "square-free" permutations?  by which I mean the permutations where no cycle length appears more than once.   This is a variant of your problem.  The answer by the same argument is very pretty:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-1/k} \Big(1 + \frac 1k\Big) = e^{-\gamma}. 
$$

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea why Lucia removed her nice answer, but here goes a short elementary argument.

We want to bound from below the expectation of $f(\pi)$, where $\pi$ is a random permutation and $f(\pi)=\prod_k 2^{m_k}/(m_k+1)!$, where $m_k=m_k(\pi)$ is a number of $k$-cycles in $\pi$. Note that $f(\pi)=1$ whenever all $m_k$ are 0 or 1 ($\pi$ is "squarefree" in Lucia's terms). So, it suffices to bound from above by a constant less than 1 the probability that $m_k>1$ for at least one value of $k$.

For given $k$, the probability that $\pi$ has at least two cycles of length $k$ does not exceed $$\frac1{n!}\cdot\frac12\cdot \frac{n!}{k!k!(n-2k)!}\cdot (k-1)!\cdot (k-1)!\cdot (n-2k)!=\frac1{2k^2},$$
here we choose two disjoint subsets of size $k$ to form cycles on them (there are $\frac12 \cdot \frac{n!}{k!k!(n-2k)!}$ choices of two sets, and $(k-1)!$ ways to make a cycle on each of them), and some permutation on remaining $n-2k$ elements.

It remains to note that $\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}<1$.

Comment: There was an oversight in what I wrote before; which is now fixed.  The convergence is not as rapid as I thought initially.